# Limit the number of max threads used by a process in linux kernel

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, threads

I think I have found something that I need from the Linux kernel that is not currently implemented.

I need a way to set a max thread limit *per process*.

Is this possible?

Comment: Just curious, why you need to limit the number of threads per process?

Comment: Are you trying to set a system-wide limit on threads per process? Or are you trying to make it so that a particular process can set its own thread limit? Or what?

Comment: I was hoping for the following functionality: "setthreadlimit -p 12543 -l 40" where -p is the pid and -l is the thread limit. So I want to be able to set a particular thread limit for a certain pid.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/344203/maximum-number-of-threads-per-process-in-linux):

Linux doesn't have a separate threads per process limit, just a limit on the total number of processes on the system (threads are essentially just processes with a shared address space on Linux) which you can view like this:

```
cat /proc/sys/kernel/threads-max
```

The default is the number of memory pages/4.  You can increase this like:

```
echo 100000 > /proc/sys/kernel/threads-max
```

There is also a limit on the number of processes (an hence threads) that a single user may create, see `ulimit/getrlimit` for details regarding these limits.

Comment: "Linux doesn't have a separate threads per process limit, just a limit on the total number of processes on the system" So it looks like what I need is not currently possible. Time to go bug the kernel devs? :P (not really though) Thanks!